# Cryptic Crossword: Turtle is ground with pepper (8)

Tags: cryptic-clues

Turtle is ground with pepper. (8)

Comment: Oops.  I am very sorry about that....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer:

> TERRAPIN
>
>  The definition is **turtle**. The wordplay is P for pepper (some pepper shakers have a P on them) inside TERRAIN or ground.

Comment: Correct!  I tried to obey cryptic crossword guidelines; sometimes they use a word to indicate a single letter (the letter the word begins with).  And sorry again about getting the count wrong, that had to be really annoying.

Comment: I'm fine with no word to indicate that pepper is an initial, since it's a common abbreviation. But I think there should be something to indicate that the initial goes inside the rest of the answer. "with" suggests juxtaposition, rather than insertion.

Comment: Turtle is ground with pepper added?

Comment: @Jiminion Yeah, that's better.

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

> SPOTTED

Reason/how I came to this

> There is a breed of turtle that is a spotted turtle - something that is spotted is sometimes referred to as peppered

Comment: Wow.  Another interesting answer, but not the right one.

Answer (score 3):

> Taking "ground" as an anagram indicator and "turtle is" as the 8 letters to be rearranged gives SLUTTIER, but I don't see how this is defined by "with pepper". If it the definition part was "with more pepper" = "spicier" = "sexier", that might work.

Comment: That's not the right answer, but it might very well be the BEST one.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be

> trouper?

---

> I did this
> `turtle`
> `ground`
> `pepper`
> and "trouper" has become something that I've distinguished as a word by reading across the lines

Comment: Interesting angle, but not the right answer.

Comment: Have you done a cryptic clue before? If not, I suggest reading about cryptic crosswords - they follow fairly precise rules and include a definition.

Comment: @Deu Sorry, I haven't -_-

Comment: @Jim Oh wait, now it is 8?..

Comment: @nicael: I was asking you: the basic idea of a cryptic clue is that there are two 'halves' to it: a definition half and a wordplay half. The definition works like regular crossword definitions, while the wordplay half gives you instructions on how to get the answer another way. For instance, "Shrink from phone in church" would have the answer "CRINGE": CE is the Church of England, and putting RING inside it (a synonym for phone) gives CRINGE, defined as "shrink".

Comment: @nicael,  yes I am very sorry I can't even count....  :(